# Display current date and time real-time (client side) on published report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a report with a column called EventTimestamp.  I want to display semi-real time how long ago that was.  I get the math portion for date span, but this report is published only once a day.  When I go to the web report it always says date difference as of publish date.  Even after refreshing the data from the report it stays as the static date.

Any ideas on making a column/measure really display current time (at least when the data is refreshed from the client/report side).

Thanks!